# setup replication under mongoDB return empty opject

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, replication

I'm tried to setup **replication** in mongoDB under Ubuntu but when I run `rs.initiate()` command I got ant empty object and does't return my replica sets

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet" }
```

and this two line added to mongod.conf file

```
replSet=name
rest=true
```

and I restart mongoDB

what I missed?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try running `ps aux | grep mongo` to ensure no other Mongo instances are running?

Comment: I ran it and it return mongodb   3285  1.2  0.6 12832880 55608 ?      Ssl  22:00   0:24 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
root      3871  0.0  0.1 609428 14100 pts/1    Sl+  22:15   0:00 mongo
root      4122  0.0  0.0  13636   976 pts/6    S+   22:33   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo

Comment: I would try to run kill on each of those process ids, then restart Mongo once more.

Comment: Great, I posted this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try running `ps aux | grep mongo` to ensure no other Mongo instances are running?

Then kill each of those process ids and restart Mongo once more.

Comment: Mr. Ben , Are you now well mongoDB, I tried to start mongo shell but I still have this error Tue Oct 29 20:19:14.962 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
and I try all solution found at stackoverflow

Comment: Seems like your server isn't running or maybe running on a different port?  You can test using the above command to see if any Mongo servers are running.

Comment: I ran it , and it return "root     29924  0.0  0.0   8076   600 pts/8    S+   20:27   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo"

Comment: It looks like your server isn't running.  Try to start it up and then start your shell.